# How to know qqPlot confidence limits?

Tags: limit, envelope

```
qqPlot(C$Safter)
```

[image: this is graph I am getting]

How can I know the limits of confidence envelope (the dotted lines)? I already ran my code also with

```
qqPlot(C$Safter, simulate=TRUE)
```

but I got an error:

```
Error in q.function(P, ...) : unused argument (simulate = TRUE)
```